# How to find loggers with wrong class names in a large Java codebase?

Tags: regex, eclipse, grep, find, negative-lookbehind

In a large code base, there may be wrong logger initializations like this:

```
public class MyClass implements Whatever {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(WrongClass.class);
```

(Should be `getLogger(MyClass.class)` instead). I am looking for a quick and dirty way to discover them without writing a whole program. False positives, if not too many (for example with inner classes) were acceptable.

I tried this regex search from within Eclipse, but it does not match on my above example:

```
(?s)(?<!class \1.*)Logger.getLogger\((\w+)\.class
```

I also thought about some `find -exec grep -q \; -print` but I didn’t get it to working either.

Comment: You want a command line `grep` to identify those files?

Comment: Just something simple that tells me which files are suspicious. It can be in Eclipse search, command line, whatever standard programmers tools can recursively check a file tree and return the suspicious file names. Writing a full java program seems so overkill for such a simple thing. I wonder if it is possible with a regex…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same challenge and didn't get it with find/grep/sed/awk etc in time. So I decided to write a small Java programm:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Files.walk(Paths.get("/path/to/sources")).filter(p -> p.toFile().isFile() && p.getFileName().toFile().getName().endsWith(".java"))
        .forEach(p -> {
            String filename = p.toFile().getName();
            String clazz = filename.split("\\.")[0];
            try {
                FileUtils.readLines(p.toFile()).forEach(line -> {
                    if (line.contains("getLog(") || line.contains("getLogger(")) {
                        if (line.matches(".*\\([ ]*" + clazz + "\\.class[ ]*\\).*")) {
                            System.out.println(String.format(" ok: %s: %s", p, line.trim()));
                        } else {
                            System.out.println(String.format("nok: %s: %s", p, line.trim()));
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
  }
```

Obviously it is quick and dirty. ;-)